# gráfico de secciones en R con ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Quiero generar un gráfico de secciones en R con ggplot2. Pero me gustaría que cada sección estuviese separada de las adyacentes. He utilizado el código que dejo abajo, añado también la imagen que se genera.

```
porcentaje <- ggplot(df2, aes(x = "", y = porcentaje, fill = porcentaje)) + geom_col(colour = "white", linewidth = 1.5) + coord_polar(theta = "y") + labs (x = NULL, y = NULL) + geom_text(aes(label = paste(año, "\n", porcentaje, "%", sep = "")), position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5), fontface = "bold", colour = "#1f4d41") + theme(
  axis.ticks = element_blank(), axis.text = element_blank(), panel.background = element_rect(fill = 'transparent'), plot.background = element_rect(fill = 'transparent', color = NA), panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
  panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), legend.position = "none") + scale_fill_gradient(low = "#acfff2", high = "#56b99e")
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como podéis ver en el código, lo que hago es añadir una línea blanca. Pero lo que quiero es que ese blanco sea una separación real transparente, para que se vea el fondo cuando lo añada a una presentación, por ejemplo.

Gracias.

Comment: Creo que una buena opción (ajena a R) es tomar el gráfico y eliminar ese blanco pasándolo a transparente con herramientas como Paint 3D

Comment: Hola, @R18. Sí, esa opción ya la tengo contemplada. Lo exporto como imagen vectorial y luego lo edito en un programa de diseño vectorial. Pero tenía la esperanza de poder hacerlo con código. Gracias.

Comment: Al darle transparente al fondo se pierden las líneas, no he conseguido solucionar el problema que comentas. Lo único la transparencia del fondo donde se explica en este link  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7455046/how-to-make-graphics-with-transparent-background-in-r-using-ggplot2

Comment: Hola, @R18. Sí, también probé a poner la línea en transparente, pero entonces se ve el color de relleno. Nada, no te preocupes. Yo creo que no se puede, porque no he encontrado nada al respecto en la red. Tocará utilizar un programa de diseño vectorial. Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Se puede configurar el color transparente de los bordes de cada porción de la torta, pero justamente al ser transparente, se termina viendo el fondo de color configurado por `fill`, como ya te mencionaron en los comentarios, lo que puedes hacer es modificar directamente la imagen `png` modificando un color por otro:

```
library(magick)

imagen <- image_read("prueba.png")
imagen_modificada <- image_transparent(imagen, "white")
image_write(imagen_modificada, "prueba-transparente.png")
```

Resultado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]